# I keep getting an error in my terminal, "error address already in use :::5000"

Tags: javascript, node.js, port

I'm following a node.js crash course and I get to the part where we are creating a server, but for some reason every time I try to run `node index` which is my js file name I'm getting the error:

> address already in use :::5000

I've looked through similar problems and tried to kill that specific port but nothing seems to work.

```
if (req.url === '/') {
  fs.readFile(
    path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'),
    (err, content) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
      res.end(content);
    }
  );
}

    
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`));
```

```
   node index 
    node:events:504
          throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
    
    Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::5000
        at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1330:16)
        at listenInCluster (node:net:1378:12)
        at Server.listen (node:net:1465:7)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/zacdistant/Documents/GUIDES AND TUTORIALS/Node JS Crash Course/index.js:91:8)
        at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1151:10)
        at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
        at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
        at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
        at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
    Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
        at emitErrorNT (node:net:1357:8)
        at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
      code: 'EADDRINUSE',
      errno: -48,
      syscall: 'listen',
      address: '::',
      port: 5000
    }
```

Comment: Which operating system are you on?

Comment: You may use this port with twice connection in you app

Comment: if you're on linux try `sudo lsof -i:5000` to get the PID of the proccess. Then `kill -9 PID`.

Comment: @jamomani Looks like Mac.

Comment: @jamomani yeah this is mac

Comment: Please, since this is a Mac specific problem, which other people might encounter as well, specify in your title and problem description that you are on a Mac terminal, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on a Mac, port 5000 and 7000 are already used by the Control Center with the AirPlay reveicer:

```
lsof -i :5000                                                              
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE              SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ControlCe 479 ****   26u  IPv4  0xa2d0e96b616f779d  0t0      TCP  *:commplex-main (LISTEN)
ControlCe 479 ****   27u  IPv6  0xa2d0e96693d0bc65  0t0      TCP  *:commplex-main (LISTEN)
```

To solve the issue you have to either change the port you use in your server like `const PORT = process.env.PORT || 9000;`, or [turn off the AirPlay receiver](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682332). Also, if you want to check before hand is the port free, run `netstat -anv -p tcp`.

Answer (score 0):

As @jamomani explained Mac uses port 5000 and 7000 that are used by the Control Center with the AirPlay receiver

To solve the issue you have to either change the port you use in your server like const PORT = process.env.PORT || 9000;, or turn off the AirPlay receiver. Also, if you want to check before hand is the port free, run netstat -anv -p tcp.